# Put nginx in maintenance mode for certain IPs

Tags: nginx

Because of the way `if` statements work in nginx (no nesting, no multiple conditions) I can't figure out a way to combine these two features:

- Using the nginx [Geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) I have a list of allowed ips
- On my filesystem if I `touch appname` in a certain dir the application automatically goes into 503 maintenance mode.

This is what I would like to do, but it's not allowed in nginx:

```
location / {
    if (-f /var/www/maintmode/appname && $allowed_ip = no) {
        return 503;
    }   
    try_files $uri;
}
```

If the above was possible in nginx, anyone on the allowed_ip list from the Geo module would bypass the 503 and get to use the site as normal. Then when verified the application is working `rm appname` from the maint dir and 503 maintenance mode ends.

The benefit of this method would be `touch`ing a single file enables/disables maint mode without ever having to modify a conf and reloading nginx.

Any ideas on how I can get something like this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the tip from HD here is how I went about solving this one:

Took advantage of this fact form the Geo docs: *When default is not specified, the default value will be an empty string.*

```
geo $allowed_client {
    10.0.0.0/8 allowed;
}

server {
    ...
    set $appname app1;
    location / {
        $maintmode "${appname}${allowed_client}"
        if (-f /var/www/maintmode/$maintmode) {
            return 503;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

so I can still `touch app1` in the maint dir to shut down a specific app, because if we have a valid IP `$maintmode = app1allowed`, which will skip past the 503. All other IPs will have `$maintmode = app1` which will fall into the 503. Thanks HD!

Answer (score 2):

If you already are using geo you should have something like this:

```
geo $client {
    default not_allowed;
    10.0.0.0/8 allowed;
}
```

So instead of using `/var/www/maintmode/appname` you could use:

```
location / {
    if (-f /var/www/maintmode/$client) {
        return 503;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```

If file `/var/www/maintmode/not_allowed` exists the page goes into maintenance mode except for the ip addresses in the allowed list.

Comment: Interesting, maybe this could be adapted. I would lose the ability to touch 'app1', 'app2' etc to be able to enable/disable multiple apps this way though